# SSIS type 2 scd with batch ID

Tags: ssis

I want to modify standard SSIS SCD behavior.

EmployeeID is my business key and title, firstname, lastname are type 2 attributes.
I want BatchLogID to reflect when a change occurred - otherwise it remains unchanged.

BatchLogID is passed to dataflow as an int

### EmployeeID,title,firstname,lastname,BatchLogID,startdate,enddate

source data

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,101 -- inserted for first time

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,102 process runs

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,103 process runs

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,104 process runs

101,Mrs, Jane,Brown,105  process runs -- only when data has changed do I want the Batch number in target updated

**target data**

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,101,101,1 jan 2000,null-- inserted for first time

101,Miss,Jane,Smith,105,105,1 jan 2000,5 Jan 2000 -- as a change is detected the data is updated

101,Mrs, Jane,Brown,105,105 jan 2000,null-- only when data has changed to I want the Batch number updated

any thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a troubleshooting website where volunteers choose to help you for free, not a code writing service.

Comment: If you have not implemented anything as yet, you can read through [this guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5632/implement-a-slowly-changing-type-2-dimension-in-sql-server-integration-services-part-1/) and then come back here should you have any specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to perform delta load using :

- Lookup and derived column
- Merge join, Conditional Split and derived column
- Change Data Capture
- Temporal tables (if the RDBMS supports that)

To know more :

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/design-the-full-load-and-delta-load-patterns-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

Used a sql merge command - had to wash through twice for

```
declare @batchLogID int= 1
MERGE dbo.targetTable AS t
USING dbo.sourceTable AS s `enter code here`
ON (t.[key] = s.[key] and t.endDate is null) 
WHEN MATCHED  and s.[value] <> t.[value] 
THEN UPDATE SET t.enddate = dateadd(ss,-1,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
WHEN not MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (key,[col1], [col2], [value], [col3],startdate,BatchLogID) 
    VALUES (s.key,s.[col1], s.[col2], s.[value], s.[col3],cast(getdate() as date),@batchLogID)
```